# making dynamic libraries for Atlas (os-x, macports)

Tags: c, macos, dll, gnu, gfortran

so i'm trying to compile Atlas (BLAS+LAPACK) on osx 10.8.2 with gnu4.7 from macports. 
For a record, this is the configuration i use:

```
../path/to/configure --prefix=/opt/atlas \
--with-netlib-lapack-tarfile=/path/to/lapack-3.4.2.tgz \
--shared \
-b 64 \
-C acg gcc-mp-4.7 \
-C if gfortran-mp-4.7
```

It goes till the end and even creates static libraries, but fails building the dynamic libraries:

```
libtool -dynamic -o ../libsatlas.dylib \
    -install_name /opt/atlas/lib/libsatlas.dylib -version-info 3.10.0 \
    -compatibility_version 3.10.0 *.o -lpthread -lm -L/opt/local/lib/gcc47/gcc/x86_64-    apple-darwin12/4.7.2/../../.. -lgfortran 
libtool: unrecognized option `-dynamic'
```

that obviously has everything to do with the lib/Makefile:

```
....
dylib:
rm -rf $(tmpd) ; mkdir $(tmpd)
cd $(tmpd) ; ar x ../liblapack.a 
cd $(tmpd) ; ar x ../libf77blas.a
cd $(tmpd) ; ar x ../libcblas.a 
cd $(tmpd) ; ar x ../libatlas.a
cd $(tmpd) ; $(LIBTOOL) -dynamic -o ../libsatlas.dylib \
    -install_name $(LIBINSTdir)/libsatlas.dylib -version-info $(VER) \
    -compatibility_version $(VER) *.o $(LIBS) $(F77SYSLIB)
rm -rf $(tmpd)
....
```

However, i could not make it work. i tried to add '--mode=link' but it still fails.

I would very much appreciate if someone could propose a modification of the Atlas makefile.

p/s/ the libtool version is: 'libtool (GNU libtool) 2.4.2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.

Used

```
/usr/bin/libtool
```

instead of gnu libtool, as well as modified the make file a little bit:

```
cd $(tmpd) ; $(LIBTOOL) -dynamic -o ../libsatlas.dylib \
    -install_name $(LIBINSTdir)/libsatlas.dylib -current_version $(VER) \
    -compatibility_version $(VER) *.o $(LIBS) $(F77SYSLIB)
```

that way dynamic library is produced.